# How to tokenize boolean expression strings?

Tags: regex, boolean-logic

I have a `boolean` expression as a string, and want to split it in a certain way.
Looking at the following example, I'd like 3 splits: `in, out, sig`:

`(in == 1'b1) | !out & (sig==1'b0)`

Probably `RegEx` will be best for splitting, but how would I define the bounds?
Maybe I need some kind of alphabet that can be used to track when a literal token starts or ends, like: `&|=()!~`
But how could I then tell that everything between `in` and `out`, which is `== 1'b1) | !`, should not be tokenized?

Comment: please, show your desired output after `regex`

Comment: As already written above, I'd like 3 splits as an array: `in, out, sig.`

Comment: Is it possible to define a token as all consecutive characters that begin with an alphabetic character that is not in the group { 'b }, and that end at the next non-alpha character?

Comment: In general: yes. Though `in` might also be written with numbers or underscopes, like `_in` `in_` `i_n` `in1`, `1_in`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(in == 1'b1) | !out & (sig==1'b0)`

We have this input. And want to find all variables.

I will use `Perl` language for algorithm, think, it simple to write.

First, let's try to find all `simple` expressions:

```
my $input = q((in == 1'b1) | !out & (sig==1'b0)); #string as input
my @expressions = split(/[|&]/,$input); 
#after that split we have:
#1) (in == 1'b1) 
#2) !out 
#3) (sig==1'b0)
#next thing, I thought, would be searhing of (!) and equations:
for my $expression (@expressions){
    $expression =~ s/^\s+//; #delete all spaces from beginning of string
    $expression =~ s/\s+$//; #delete all spaces at end of string
    $expression =~ s/^[\(](.+)[\)]$/$1/; #delete round brackets
    #here you must check, if we have round brackets, some kind of iteration must be here

    $expression =~ s/^!//; #find first (!), it can be here 
    my ($left, $right) = split(/!=|==/,$expression);
    #ok, now check, if left or right operand a variable:
    if($left eq "1'b1" or $left eq "1'b0"){
        #not our variable
    } 
    else{

       #our variable, $left ;)
    }
    if ($right eq "1'b1" or $right eq "1'b0"){
        #not our variable
    }
    else{
       if(defined($right) and $right!=""){
        #our variable $right
       }

    }

}
```

but, as I see, that you have something simple here.

So, you want to find all variables here.

`/(?<!1|b|')[a-zA-Z_\d]+(?!(0|1|'))/`